# What's the error in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my javascript code, I'm getting error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL                                            at Line no 37`

I was trying to append the options to "select" list from a json, my code seems to be have no syntax error. but chrome is throwing one.

```
31 set_options_list = function(selctelm, json){
32  $(selctelm).empty();
33  $.each(json, function(k, val) {
34     $(selctelm).append(
35              $("<option></option>").text(val).val(val)
36     )
37  });​
38 }
```

Comment: explain it more details

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin : Added description pease check.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an invisible char (**zero-width space U+200B**) after `});` in line 37.

[image: I copied your code to my editor]

Comment: This is also visible when pasting the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5ZJL/

Answer (score 1):

Remove illigeal character

Try this Jquery;

```
set_options_list = function(selctelm, json){
$(selctelm).empty();
$.each(json, function(k, val) {
$(selctelm).append($("<option></option>").text(val).val(val)); // Here semicolon
 });​//Here there is illegal character
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out your code missing some tag.

```
set_options_list = function(selctelm, json) {
    $(selctelm).empty();
    $.each(json, function(k, val) {
        $(selctelm).append(
        $("<option></option>").text(val).val(val));
    });
};
```